# Add a UITapGestureReconizer to a UIImage

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITapGestureReconizer` set up with my `view` but I only want the `selector` to be called when the `view` tapped is this picture I have. I tried adding the `recognizer` to the `imageView` both programmatically and via the storyboard but neither worked. It only works for my `view`. Here is the code.

```
var tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer?
```

and in my `viewDidLoad` I have

```
tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer!)
```

my image is a variable as well

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of the `UIImageView` to `true` and then modify your code for that

```
self.mainImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer!)
```